# Need a formula to count how many times individual cells are greater than or equal to a value in a different cell while referencing another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows-11

I'm looking for a formula to count how many times the numbers in Column B exceed the values in Column C while referencing the name in Column A if possible.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image: screenshot of workbook]

Comment: Can you post your attempts at doing this? What have you done so far to achieve this goal? This site is not a free scripting service. The community here helps those who help themselves. So if you have attempted to do something to achieve this goal, please post your code/script/formula and the community can attempt to help you. As it stands this question reads as a free scripting request and will most likely be closed as a result.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't realize I needed to post my failed attempts too. I'll be sure to do so if I ever have another question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Office 365 or Office 2021 you can use FILTER function.

See below sample.

[image]

Formula in I2 is

```
=SUM(IF(FILTER($E$3:$E$12,$D$3:$D$12=H2)>FILTER($F$3:$F$12,$D$3:$D$12=H2),1,0))
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+ <kbd>ENTER</kbd> from within the formula bar to create an Array Formula. This step is required.

Select and drag it down.

Replace , (Comma) with ; (Semi colon) if that's the list separator for your regional settings.

---

If you do not have O365 or 2021 try the below formula. Again this must be created as an Array Formula by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+ <kbd>ENTER</kbd> from within the formula bar

```
=SUM(IF($D$3:$D$12=H2,IF($E$3:$E$12>$F$3:$F$12,1,0),0))
```

Comment: I was able to use the first formula b/c I have Office 365 & it worked perfectly. Thank you for your time Patkim.